# asp.NET SessionState - SQLServer - "random" characters at the end of SessionID in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server session state. When I login and an entry goes into the ASPStateTempSessions, with the appropriate info, there is a somehwat of a random string of characters, attached to my SessionID in the DB.

```
SessionId
30qsfnfzp3bfoyea5di4jty1173d75c7
lpt02vk0trt35nt4esjnilc57ec269a3
lpt02vk0trt35nt4esjnilc5815cba00
r2uw0cx2qx4vkyrjavyvxbzg815cba00
sxshd05trik4jzrzlppvajii173d75c7
txzuktz13kzr5vc2ptgrpmlz173d75c7
```

What are these and how can i control them ?

Comment: Why do you want to control them?

Comment: They need to run free huh ? :) I need to be able to search for them in the DB , but when i get SessionID in C#, these "random" few chars are not there, and I'd really rather search for a specific string, instead of using things like .contains and so on.